# C: how to structure if-else statements

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm trying to build a weather calculator for a class.

The problem seems to be with my if-else statements. The if's are supposed to print out separate statements about weather conditions based on average temperatures. For some reason, the program always outputs the second statement: "\nThese two weeks were quite hot".

How can I structure my if-else statements correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int high_temp[14];
    int warmdays = 0, colddays = 0, i = 0;
    float average = 0.0f, sum = 0.0f;


    printf("\nWeather Analyzer Application by Joey Peters");
    for(i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        printf("\n\nPlease enter the temperature for day #%d ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &high_temp[i]);

        sum += high_temp[i];

        if(high_temp[i] > 60){
            warmdays++;
        }

        if(high_temp[i] < 60){
            colddays++;
        }


    }

        average = sum / 14;
        printf("\nThe number of warm days: %d", warmdays);
        printf("\nThe nuber of cold days: %d", colddays);
        printf("\nThe average high temperature: %.2f", average);

        if(average = 100 || average >= 90 ){
            printf("These two weeks were blazing hot");
        }
    else    
        if(average >= 80 || average <= 89){
            printf("\nThese two weeks were quite hot");
        }
    else    

        if(average >= 70 || average <= 79){
            printf("\nThese two weeks hot for Michigan");
        }
    else    

        if(average >= 60 || average <= 69){
            printf("\nThese two weeks were decent for Michigan");
        }
    else    
        if(average >= 50 || average <= 59){
            printf("\nThese two weeks were somewhat cold");
        }
    else
        if(average < 50){
            printf("\nThese two weeks were basically cold");
        }   

    printf("\n\nThank you for using the weather analyzer!");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `x >= 80 || x <= 89` is true for all x. You might want to rethink your conditions.

Comment: `average = 100` is an assignment, not a comparison, and will always evaluate true.

Comment: Thanks I was being dumb.

Comment: No, not dumb, it has happened to us all... The key to C is to simply "*slow down*", think through each character of your code, and most importantly, **enable warnings**, e.g. use `-Wall -Wextra` in your compiler options and do not accept code until it compiles cleanly -- without a single warning.

Comment: "*`if (average = 100) ...`*": Having used [*Yoda Conditions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions) had helped to avoid this common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The line where you have

`if(average = 100 || average >= 90 )`

You are assigning 100 to x, instead of comparing it. Change it to this:

`if(average == 100 || average >= 90 )`

Or simplify it further by changing it to

`if(average >= 90 )`

Since there's no point in checking if `average` is 100 if you're already checking if it's greater than 90.

Also, if you're checking if `average` is in between 2 numbers, like 80 and 89 for example, use the `&&` operator:

`if(average >= 80 && average <= 89)`